# Out of memory: cannot create a new native thread

Tags: java, multithreading, operating-system

I'm working on a application where the client (user) has the control to create new thread and kill them. The application is based on Java.

In one of the cases, user creates multiples threads and kills them and creates new one's and goes on. After some time, OutofMemoryException pops up. I thought this is related to thread stack issue. So I reduced the thread stack XSS from 1024KB to 512KB and also reduced the Java heap size from Xms 256mb XmX 1024mb to Xms 256mb Xmx 512mb.

I also memory profiled the application with yourkit, just to see whether it overflows from the heap size. but it seems to be okay..threads are created and kills okay.

This is 8GB RAM Windows 7 machine

I was wondering, what else can be causing this exception?

Comment: How are you killing those threads? Are you sure you're `join`ing them all?

Comment: I bet you it's a bug in your code, you should post some ;)

Comment: Without code it's very difficult to answer. How do you kill thread? The safe way is to return from public void run() method.

Comment: @Isaac when the threads runnable is done executing, the thread stops (die's). yes we join them all

Comment: How many threads are in existence at any given point in time? It could be possible that you are reaching the maximum number of threads available to your process. Especially if the threads are not garbage collected...

Comment: And have you considered using a thread pool or executor so that threads can be reused when it's current job is done?

Comment: Question remains - how exactly are you killing those threads? you mentioned that, in the case with the `OutOfMemoryException`, the user creates **and kills** threads. How is thread killing done?

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 main causes of this.

1. Memory leaks
2. Inefficient Algorithms
3. Heap size being too small

These usually can be fixed by the following:

1. Memory leaks - de-referencing unneeded objects
2. Inefficient Algorithms - providing more memory efficient algorithms (sometimes less is better)
3. Heap size - Increasing the heap size